# NSPredicate and NSString Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nspredicate, nsnumber

I have the following predicate that works fine with numbers such as 555 and 623 (3 digit numbers)

The problem is, I have numbers such as 005 and 009 etc (1 digit with two 0 before).

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY code BETWEEN %@",
                                    [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
                                     [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [self.predicateFilter floatValue]]],
                                     [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: [NSNumber numberWithFloat: [self.predicateFilter floatValue] + .99]],
                                     nil]];
```

Most of the time, predicateFilter will be a string with number like `@"124"`.  But when I run a number like 035 (notice the 0 at beggining), I get the following NSLog:

```
2011-08-13 18:32:23.989 Codes[2007:707] code 004
2011-08-13 18:32:24.018 Codes[2007:707] ANY code BETWEEN {4, 4.99}
2011-08-13 18:34:23.846 Codes[2007:707] code 083
2011-08-13 18:34:23.864 Codes[2007:707] ANY code BETWEEN {83, 83.99}
```

So it is not finding those numbers because of the `00X`.

Is there a way I can do an if/else or something that catches all numbers that have a `0` or `00` to begin with, so I can edit the predicate accordingly?

EDIT:

I think I just need to make a predicate that matches the first 3 digits of `code` to an NSString, which as 005.  Then that would give me the rest of the results that are 005.5, 005.6, etc.

Comment: What type does the `code` attribute that you're filtering have?

Comment: It is a `string` but its numbers, not letters.  Basically the predicate right now is not finding any `code` which start with `0` or `00`.

Comment: Leading zeros have no meaning in a numeric expression. If they do have a meaning for your codes (004 != 4), you should use strings. If they don't, use a numeric attribute.

Comment: `code` is a already a string.  And I need to keep it as 005 cause this is a preloaded database.  The problem I'm having is the predicate right now is not finding any code which start with 0 or 00

Comment: Why don't you just query with your predicateFilter directly instead of first converting it to a number (which removes the leading zeros)?

Comment: Are you sure `code` is a string and not a number?

Comment: Yes code is a string, I'm looking at the property right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since *code* is a string can you do a MATCH comparison instead, or is this core data. If it is core data can you add a property to return *code* as an Integer *codeInteger* perhaps using [transient attribute](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/08/08/transient-entities-and-core-data/).

Comment: I can but I don't think that is necessary as there are only a few `code` that are under 100.  There has to be a way for me to make an if/else statement to collect all `code` that begin with `0` or `00`, then I can create a separate predicate for those ones.

Comment: It seems to me that your problem is that you are doing a string comparison with you between and not a number ones, if this is the case can you try turn your two between values into string and then pad them out with zeros if required.